# Creating Test EntityList objects - RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm creating an EnityList to do some client side testing with my ViewModel.  Something like:

```
   var people = new EntityList<Person>()
    {
        new Incident() {Age = 55, Name="Joe"},
        new Incident() {Age=42, Name="Sam"}
    };
```

The problem is that the implicit (and explicit) Adds fail.  The entitylist is created as **read-only**.  Any thoughts on how to create a test EntityList?

Comment: I am having this problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing testing then you probably don't want an EntityList. I would expect that a ViewModel shouldn't know about the EntityList, but rather should just get access to an IEnumberable instead. Both EntityList and List expose this, so in your tests you can just create a List.

I realize this doesn't help with the issue of EntityList being read-only. :)

Comment: I think you're right.  I was under the mistaken impression that the type exposed on the ViewModel had to implement INotifyCollectionChanged, but apparently the binding engine will try a cast from IEnumerable<> if that's what you have exposed.  Er.  I hope anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need an EntityContainer to own your EntityList.

Comment: Your blog is most helpful!  Unfortunately, even with that help (and reflector), I wasn't able to create the EntityList<>.  lol.